# ViewHelper in NinaOldAndroid does not work outside of onCreate() method

Tags: android, android-animation

I try to set `ViewHelper.setPivotY(test, 0);` in method `onClick()` but it doesn't work. The animation still scale to the centerY. Here is my code. I don't know where I am wrong?

public class NewClassTest extends Activity{

```
LinearLayout test;
FrameLayout content;
Button btn;

boolean toggle = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

    test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);

    content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    content.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // ViewHelper.setPivotY(test, 0); does not work
            runAnimation(toggle);
            toggle = !toggle;
        }
    });
    ViewHelper.setPivotY(test, 0); // work

}

private void runAnimation(boolean in){
    AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator anim = null, anim2 = null;
            // ViewHelper.setPivotY(test, 0); also does not work
    if(in){
        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(test, "scaleY", 1, 1 - (((float)content.getHeight()) / ((float) test.getHeight())));
        anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(content, "translationY", content.getHeight(), 0);
        animSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }else {
        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(test, "scaleY", 1 - ((float)content.getHeight()) / ((float) test.getHeight()), 1);
        anim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(content, "translationY", 0, content.getHeight());
        animSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                content.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
    animSet.setDuration(1000).play(anim2).with(anim);
    animSet.start();
}
```

Thank for your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happen to me also. test it on HTC One S with android 4.1 and that wasn't worked, but in Samsung Galaxy I with android 2.2 it worked as expected.

Changed it to `ViewHelper.setPivotY(test, 0.00000001f);` solved it =\

Don't know if it's a bug of HTC, android or nineoldandroids